# Mule maven build updating config.resource property of mule-deploy.properties failed for a newly created mule project which was not deployed anytime

Tags: maven, mule

I have use case to build a mule project using maven and i experienced a scenario where if a new mule project created in mule studio with multi flows which was not run/deployed anytime.

I performed a maven build for the mule project There were two observations

1) when the mule build deployed in mule stand alone it got  deployment failure with error

org.mule.module.launcher.InstallException: Config for app ...not found....mule-config.xml.

2)when i checked the config.resource property of  mule-deploy.properties was not assigned(config.resources=) with flow config file .

Please let me know any suggestions where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is just update the property with the name of the config xml in mule-deploy.properties.

```
config.resources=my-projects-config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to <>/src/main/app/mule-deploy.properties, verify config.resources=test.xml<>. If any other files are assigned, remove it.

or
2) Keep a dummy mule-config.xml in the directory src/main/app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.0/mule.xsd">

    <!-- empty config to avoid the hot deployment classloader choking on a missing config file -->

</mule>
```

Although we create a "default" application in the "apps" folder, it's empty and thus hot deploy complains about a missing mule-config.xml file